# Awesomplete plugin go to url on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-plugins

I have Awesomplete plugin and it returns me value from API. That's all working but I want to have possibility go to url on select, I was trying with windos loaction but without success.  So far my code looks like this:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/alljobs/", true);
ajax.onload = function() {
var list = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText).map(function(i) {return   i.title.rendered; i.acf.link; window.location.href= i.acf.link});
new Awesomplete(document.querySelector("#list"),{ list: list });};
ajax.send();
```

Any ideas, help :-)

Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

I solve this, here is the code:

```
  var input=$("#list")[0]; new Awesomplete(input, {list: list});$("#list").on('awesomplete-selectcomplete',function(){
window.location.href = this.value;});
```